# How to change ip address used by Zimbra zcs 8.6

Tags: linux, email-server, zimbra

For postfix I can change the binded ip by changing parameter like

`smtp_bind_address = 192.168.146.197` in main.cf

How to change the ip address binded by zimbra(server have multi ip's) ?

Comment: http://blogs.reliablepenguin.com/2008/03/29/bind_zimbra_on_specific_ip_address

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same process editing the /opt/zimbra/postfix/conf/main.cf (like root).

So restart postfix with zimbra user

postfix reload

and must work like you need.

Answer (score 0):

For Zimbra 8.7:

1. Open /opt/zimbra/common/conf/main.cf.default file for editing with your favorite editor (e.g. vi).
2. add smtp_bind_address = 192.168.146.197
3. su - zimbra
4. zmmtactl restart

Answer (score 0):

Adding the last action is to change your old IP address from all relevant DNS records and relay hosts or else you may face a mail send/receive problem in spite of a fully functional Zimbra server.

If you have upgraded to the latest version of Zimbra and still facing the issue with Changing IP addresses, here is the link you should follow for the step-by-step instructions.

https://community.zextras.com/how-to-change-ip-address-of-zimbra-server/